# Constant Contact plugin forbidden error

Tags: plugins

I am developing site in local. it works fine. but when i setup that on client server in the join us form after clicking join button the following error occurred.
I am using `constant contact api` plugin for join us page.

```
"You don't have permission to access /demo/wp-content/plugins/constant-contact-api/form.php on this server."
```

I tried setting permissions to 777 temporarily on the setup folder, but that gave me a bigger error. Is this a server problem?

Or how can i solve this...please guide me...

Comment: Look at your webserver error logs, I have encountered setups of Apache wherein files and directories were required to have 0 permissions for group and all. More information on the deployment environment would also be good to have - server versions, etc.

Comment: See it this helps: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96408/upgrade-wordpress-multisite-to-3-5-1-problems/96454#96454