# Handle lots of images within the media uploader / selector

Tags: media, media-library

I currently have a website containing more than 3K images (and counting...) within the media library.

When the user opens the Media Uploader to select or upload an image to a post the media selector freezes and/or crashes while fetching the excessive amount of thumbnails.

I'm obviously looking for a way to fix this but not sure what direction I should take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with WordPress itself; WordPress is fully scalable with appropriate hardware.

"the media selector freezes." Do you mean the whole browser window? Or the popup media library window?

The issue is going to be 1) the host server not having enough memory or bandwidth or CPU to display the page and number of images, or 2) the end user browser freezing from lack of memory.

Comment: Thanks for pointing towards the right direction. The issue was exactly that the client had uploaded pictures that were too big for the server to generate the thumbs. Therefore these massive images were loaded in lieu of the non-existent thumbnails which in its turn crashed the browser.

Answer (score 0):

No, the issue is with WordPress itself. If admin interface split images previews to the pages in the grid option as it does in the list option, the problem would not exist. So, it is the exactly new WordPress relies problem.