# Transfered live site to new server and images are not showing

Tags: images, uploads, media-library, paths

i just recently transfered a new site to a server. All paths are correct when I debug the site but for some reason the uploads front and back do not show either in the media section or the site pages.

In the media area I get the thumbnails and file names but they do not show up. It is almost like it knows they are there but it does not want to show them.

I have set all permissions to 777 in uploads and still no joy at all.

Does anyone know what this could be?

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: ... really sounds like a permissions issue. See if this helps: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96454/21376

Comment: you have set file permissions. But have you checked for .htaccess file?

Comment: yeah .htaccess looks fairly normal to me. The hosting is on a 1and1 server so that may be the issue too. Not sure if PHP safemode is off or on.

Comment: Can you test it with some `phpinfo()`?

Comment: if I add phpinfo() what will that tell me?

Comment: And make sure your _directories_ have execute permissions all the way through to your images.

Comment: yes that worked a treat, I had to slap into into submission to get that to work.