# Why I can download any file except PHP files from a URL but I can download any from another site?

Tags: php, htaccess

all,

I've been struggling with this for the past two days, I just can't find the answer - sorry if I post this in the wrong site but this is the best option I could think of.

I have some problems with a site that I troubleshot all the way until they led me to this particular problem. If I want to download a PHP file browsing to its parent directory I'm not able to, something about the file not being found. I can, however, download any other type of file from this site.

http://nextgenerationattorney.org/wp-content/plugins/wp-import-txt/

In contrast, I can go to another site, browse to the same directory, and I'm able to download any file without problems.

http://nextgenlawyer.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-import-txt/

I thought this might be a problem caused by .htaccess restrictions, but I copied the .htaccess file from the working URL to the non working and it still does not work - I don't need to restart apache for this to take effect, do I?

I'm just out of ideas, I tried copying the whole directory from the working site, permissions are the same on both, I don't know what else to try.

Anybody can share out any other idea? If more information is needed please let me know.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Sorry, why do you want this kind of unrestricted download access? I make an effort to _prevent_ this sort of thing.

Comment: I really don't want this, but I tracked down my original problem with a plugin to this, my plugin attempts to load a script but it gets a "not found" error, so I tried manually by going to the plugin's directory and I found I cannot download it myself even though I can on another site

Comment: This question was migrated from serverfault.com, although I'm not sure it fits the criteria to be posted there, I'm quite sure my problem has nothing to do with Wordpress... anyone thinks otherwise?

Comment: Ok. The real problem is different from the one you are asking about.

Comment: It is  a bit of a judgment call but it is plausibly a WordPress server configuration issue, which is OK per the [faq] (as I read it).

Comment: Yes, I just felt it would be easier to understand like this. If I get the file to be downloaded, my Wodpress problem will be fixed.

Comment: You know what? you're right. I just created a directory in my root folder with a php file on it and I'm able to download it... didn't think of that... so I guess, it IS a Wordpress configuration issue... Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Have a look into the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) :)

Comment: @s_ha_dum touche....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem already, it WAS a permissions issue but not where I thought it would be - I looked for the plugins directory, the plugin directories and files, but I had to go a little  back down the directory tree, back to  wp-content directory.

Old permissions were **775**, I just set them to **755** and it works like a charm now. I wouldn't think it would matter, but it does apparently.

Thanks to everyone that helped me with this question.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is configured correctly, a request to a PHP file is forwarded to the PHP interpreter. It does not play a role if it is accessed directly, via a link or by clicking on it in a directory listing.

I visited both of your URLs. URL 2 shows an error message - an PHP error message. This file has definitely been processed by the PHP interpreter:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in /home/nextgenl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-import-txt/wp-import-txt.php on line 24`

The first URL redirects to the main script, with the called file as parameter. It seems to be a Rewrite Configuration here. And there you are right, it should take place in your .htaccess.

For my wordpress installation, I use this `.htaccess` for URL rewriting:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I already tried a working .htaccess - inluding yours - in the root directory of my installation but the problem still happens. The problem is that one of the php files loads another one and it fails, I thought it was a bad file but no, because I copied the file from the working site, do you have any other idea?

Comment: You might want to check your Apache configuration for the directory you deployed the blog to. Try an `AllowOverride all` to make sure your `.htaccess` can have an effect.

Comment: Do you think this .htaccess directive could make a difference if I put it inside the plugins directory? I'll give that a try

Comment: nope, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

> ... my plugin attempts to load a script but it gets a "not found"
> error, so I tried manually by going to the plugin's directory and I
> found I cannot download it myself even though I can on another site

This sounds like a permissions problem. Some of your files or directories have owner or group permissions that aren't allowing the file to load. Be aware that what you can see/load directly is not always the same as what the server can load. It depends on how the file is being accessed. It if very difficult to say exactly what is misconfigured though.

I would take a look at the file permissions on the server that works and set the permissions to match on the server that does not work. Your owner and group could well be different though. [The Codex has information that will help you get that.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Finding_Server_Info)

If you don't have access to the server configuration or this doesn't make sense to you, ask your host for help. You *can* break things-- probably not permanently but it would certainly be stressful.

## Resources

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96454/21376

Comment: Thanks, that was my first guess at the problem, but the permissions were correct...

Comment: Please pay attention to the _owner_ and _group_ parts. People forget about those components. Permissions are not global. They are connected to the owner and group of the files and the permissions on the folders all the way down the line matter-- folders need to be executable.

Comment: Owner and Group are correct: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uqfhbnxck86rlz3/nextgene-plugin-file-permissions.txt

Comment: Ok, this might help in identifying the issue... I mentioned the plugin "loads" a php file and it comes up with "not found", this is the line that uses this php file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/94yjvgtnhitmbjv/php-line.txt