# How do I force WP to set upload directory permissions correctly?

Tags: uploads, permissions

I installed a fresh copy of Wordpress 3.7.1 last week and uploaded an image using the media uploader. The image was uploaded alright, I could see it with FTP, but requesting it returned an HTTP error 404. WP had set the permissions of the directories `uploads`, `2013` and `11` to 0754. So I set them to 0755, and everything was fine.

Now it's December so WP had to create the `12` directory. It again choose to set it to 0754.

Any ideas on what might be wrong? Isn't it supposed to use the parent directory's permissions? And what I can do to fix this? FYI, `wp-contents` has 0755.

**Edit:** Files and folders are owned by the user the web server runs as, and group ownership seems OK too.
I've now also tried setting directory permissions for `wp-content`, `uploads` and `2013` to 0775. Uploaded an image: the `12` directory got 0754 again.

**Edit 2:** OK, I guess I'll have to get in touch with my provider. It's a cheap hosting account, no shell access, certainly no access to the web server config.

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96454/21376

Comment: I've edited/updated my question.

Comment: WordPress doesn't set permissions, your server does.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't it supposed to use the parent directory's permissions?

No, according to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/351582/file-permissions-created-by-apache) file permissions n creation are set by apache. You will need to look at your apache config and OS settings to find the reason and fix it.

It it might be that your umask parameter is 003 instead of 002.