# permissions on themes directory

Tags: themes, editor, permissions

I have a `ftp` user like owner of all files and directories. When I try to modify any file (e.g. `styles.css`) with Editor from Admin Panel I see this message:

```
To save the changes, is needed that the file has write permissions. Visit the codex for more information.
```

(I've translated the message so it won't be the exact text in english)

I've tried to change group owner to my Admin Panel user name and give `0664` permissions to all files inside the theme directory, but it doesn't work:

```
cd /wp-content/themes
chown -R ftpuser:adminPanel twentythirteen/
find twentythirteen/ -type f | xargs chmod -R 0664 //this will change all files inside `twentythirteen` (not directories) into 0664 mode
```

The only way I've found to achieve it is giving `666` permissions:

```
find twentythirteen/ -type f | xargs chmod -R 0666
```

but I don't want it.

How could I handle this?

Comment: Same answer as here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96454/21376

Comment: @s_ha_dum - If I give write permissions to server user (`www-data` in my case), any server user could change the files. Is there a way to let only the Admin Panel user to change those files?

Comment: If you are on a shared server, yes, that is a bit of a problem and a hard one to get around. My honest advice is "Don't use the built in editor." It is like working on an airplane while the plane is in the air. Just don't do it.