# How to solve: An error occured in the upload

Tags: uploads, attachments, errors

[image]
This error message appears when I try to upload any picture. Currently I am using WordPress 3.8.

Comment: Probably a file permission problem. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96454/21376

Comment: Please see this link for more details - it helped me
https://sebastian.expert/fix-wordpress-an-error-occurred-in-the-upload-please-try-again-later/ Basically what it says is to use Developer tools in Chrome or Firefox to see the response from async_upload.php file after uploading files (when error message appears). It returns error details in JSON format. Having details it will be easier to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to read but that error is a common one and it is also common to find no obvious cause. Try renaming the file, I see a special character in it. Double check the image is not actually uploaded because sometimes it will upload despite the error. Try uploading other images of different file-types to establish more information for troubleshooting. If still struggling try installing another WP in another directory on your hosting and see what happens within that blog. If both continue to fail consider hosting service settings or just permission issues.

Good luck.

UPDATE: I'm having the same issue in a new blog. Must be a new bug in Wordpress. The image does upload though. Play around with the tabs and menus. After uploading, seeing the error then selecting "Uploaded to this post" under the Media Library tab I can see the image.

Comment: "Error slide-1.jpg
An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."
This the message that appeared in the screen

Comment: Check the size of the file - WordPress default upload maximum may be too low for you.

Answer (score -1):

After long suffer, just figured out that i had following in my functions.php:

```
if ( is_admin() ) { ?>  
    <style>
        * {
            font-family: Arial;  
        }
    </style>
<?php 
}
```

I removed it and it worked, probably caused of `is_admin()` function.