# owner/group issue on server

Tags: uploads

We are having some issues in regards to our WordPress and Apache2 Ubuntu server.

The issue is that the WordPress install is under a different group/owner than the root. This is causing issues with writing files to the directory.

If I change the owner/group then it causes other problems with our ftp server. Is there a workaround for this.

Comment: You have to get the owner and group of the webserver an that of the FTP user synced up. How you would do that is not especially WordPress specific, though there are a number of related questions/answers here. This may be better asked on a different Stack. That said, see: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/96408/21376

Answer (score 0):

The code should be owned by the FTP User and Group, but then have permissions set wide enough to allow the webserver to read the files. Typically this is 644 for files and 755 for directories.

More information:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Permission_Scheme_for_WordPress